# I cannot import a module into python

Tags: python, django, python-module

I'm taking a django course and when I go to put urls, it's causing this problem:
[image]

Code:
[image]

Folder structure:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `from sistematrf.core.views import home`

Comment: Results in an answer: Unresolved reference 'sistematrf'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of absolute imports being in effect (more precisely, the lack of implicit relative imports) for Python 3 and the fact that the `pyping` module was most likely only written for Python 2. Whereas in Python 2 you can do:

```
from core.views import home
```

In Python 3 (or if you have `from __future__ import absolute_import` in Python 2), you have to do:

```
from .core.views import home
```

or

```
from pyping.core.views import home
```

You can try this.

Answer (score 0):

So to import the views from core you should do

```
from core import views as core_views
```

then in your main projects urls.py you can use this by

```
path('',core_views.home,name='home)
```

You should also make sure that your app core, is in the INSTALLED APPS in your main projects Settings.py

Also make sure that in your core.views that a view exists for home

Lmk if this works